# Remove empty decimal values Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm building a calculator app and I'm trying to get the text.label to only display decimal values if they are not empty, for example; 5 + 5 = 10, at the moment it shows 10.0 because I am using floats. Do I create a function that I call every time before I print the result to the screen, that seems unnecessary to me?

Comment: Just use NumberFormatter minimumFractionDigits = 0

Comment: That won't work because I still need it to show decimal values when there are supposed to be, for example 5.2 + 5 = 10.2

Answer (score 1):

**Extension**

**Swift 3**

```
extension Float {
   var cleanValue: String {
       return self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
   }
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
extension Float {
    var cleanValue: String {
        return self % 1 == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
    }
}
```

Usage

```
 var sampleValue: Float = 3.234
 print(sampleValue.cleanValue)
 //Output = 3.234
 sampleValue = 3
 print(sampleValue.cleanValue)
 //Output = 3
```

Comment: This doesn't compile in Swift 3.

Comment: Thanks that looks right, and it works in Playground but in Project I get the error: Instance member 'cleanValue' cannot be used on type 'Float'. BTW this is the code: result = "\(Float.cleanValue(leftValStr)! * Float.cleanValue(rightValStr)!)"

Comment: You need to move your codw inside viewDidLoad or any other method

Comment: I created a new Swift file called DecimalCleaner.swift but get the error: "Invalid redeclaration of 'cleanValue'" - huh?